# Folder.Bind() Stuck when using Subscriptions for multiple accounts through EWS Managed API

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am using a streaming subscription (EWS Managed API) to subscribe to events on one mailbox. Now, instead of doing this directly, **I want to subscribe and take action on incoming mails on these mailboxes through impersonation.** 
How to achieve it?

> What I have Tried:

I did setup multiple streaming subscriptions using `service.ImpersonatedUserId()` but when i get a event(i get events successfully for the 2 mailboxes i have subscribed to) and try to take some action for e.g `EmailMessage.Bind(Item Id)` or `Folder.Bind()`, the code **stucks**! I dont get any error message. I even tried `TraceEnabled= true`, I found nothing!

I did see [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/8bcc0322-cd6a-49df-8342-24828135d0d3/ews-managed-api-folderbind-hangs-when-using-impersonation?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) MSFT link but didn't find an answer. 
I need help with for e.g moving the mail to another folder for multiple mailboxes through EWS subscriptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default concurrent connection limit in .net is 2 by default https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.7.2 because Streaming notifications require a concurrent connection to work this is a common issue.So all you should need to do is set the connection limit higher eg

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
```

Comment: Thank you Glen for helping millions of us with our issues in Exchange and O365! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey @GlenScales, Can you also please answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52178314/10091625) ?.

Comment: @Glen Scales, this answer was a life saver. We were trying to do something similar and it is not at all obvious that one needs to set this global property for to connect to multiple email accounts from the same process. Thank you so much!