# How to Close a Streaming Subscription for a particular mailbox in EWS API?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have a EWS Managed API code running with `multiple streaming subscriptions.`
I want to **terminate** (or restart) the connection to a **specific mailbox** on the basis of some conditions.

How to use the `connection.close()` (or any other way) to close a **particular** subscription id?

> Any idea how to force close a streaming subscription connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connections can contain one more more Mailboxes depending on how your doing affinity. You just close the connection the mailbox is in itself https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.streamingsubscriptionconnection.close?view=exchange-ews-api . Then remove the Subscription for that mailbox and restart the connection.

Comment: **I am creating a new connection for every user i impersonate.** Will you guide the right way to create subscriptions?. ( I have read the affinity link, but not reallysure how to implement it! It will be great if you provide a sample code!

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the sample on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2013/06/04/ews-streaming-notifications-and-exchange-2013-and-office-365-wave-15/ which implements this logic